# Optimizations for Knapsack with 3 dimensions

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

**Problem Statement:**

I am given a set of prices for \$n\$ items I have to find out what is the maximum value I can get with \$M\$ money by selecting exactly \$C\$ items without exceeding the amount of money I have. Obviously \$C \leq N\$.

**Solution:**

The code for the above problem is developed using the suggestions taken from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18529/76136). The code in java is given below:

```
public class KnpMD {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int items[] = {4,6,9,10};
        int M = 12;
        int C = 2;

        int dp[][][] = new int[items.length+1][M+1][C+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < items.length+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < M+1; j++) {
                for(int k = 1; k <= C; k++) {
                    dp[i][j][k] = -1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 1 ; j < M + 1; j++) {

                for(int k = 1; k <= C; k++) {

                    dp[i+1][j][k] = dp[i][j][k];// to Copy all previous optimal states found.

                    if(items[i] > j)
                        continue;

                    if(dp[i][j-items[i]][k-1] != -1)
                        dp[i+1][j][k] = Math.max(dp[i+1][j][k],
                                dp[i][j-items[i]][k-1] + items[i]);
                }
            }


        }

        System.out.println(dp[items.length][M][C]);
    }
}
```

What are some of the improvments I can add to this code?  I am unable to follow the optimzations suggested in the answer linked above.

Can someone tell me what is the meaning of the statement(linked in the above answer)

> In the preceding formulae, we retrieved the optimal solution which
>   consisted of no more than (k−1)(k−1) items among the first (j−1)(j−1)
>   as Ti,j−1,k−1Ti,j−1,k−1. However, it should be clear that this is
>   precisely equal to maxp=0,j−1{Ti,p}maxp=0,j−1{Ti,p} just by using the
>   original table!! ie., the optimal solution with no more than kk items
>   can be also retrieved by considering the optimal solutions with 1
>   item, 2 items, 3 items, ... (j−1)(j−1) items ...

Any other improvments would be greatly appreciated.